# Google Map API for iOS , Show only particular Place

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-2, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm new to google Map and iOS, and currently I'm learning it. I have a Map in my iPad app which only to show particular place. Must not scroll all over the world map. for example, if I mentioned India means, it must show only India, do not scroll or show other places . and it can zoom out and zoom in only to India. How can I achieve this ? whether can I use Google map iOS API or Web API ? kindly help me , thanks in Advance .

Update :

Is there is anyway to do same this concept on Jquery Map API ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading between the lines that you want to confine a user to say India, but not to just a single view of India. You can have your ViewController implement [GMSMapViewDelegate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p) to track where a user is scrolling to, and then if they get outside your bounds you can animate the map view back to the safe zone.

Alternatively, if you are just interested in a single view of India, you could configure the map in your viewDidLoad, and then turn off zoom and scroll gestures by setting the GMSUISettings [scrollGestures](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings#a2d9e62a5b4d7d9d5c60760f0a2566059), [zoomGestures](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings#a22f1ab66feb66df0be1287473bcdbf22) and kin to NO.